# Why is my android app crashing on startup after being installed from play store?

Tags: android

I've published an android app on play store in Open Beta Phase. One of my friend was downloading it from play store. But on startup, it's throwing org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException error. He's running it on Android 4.4. Any idea what is wrong with the code?

Here is the stack trace :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class ImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.aura.androidapp.Browse.GenreAdapter.getView(Browse.java:709)
    at com.aura.androidapp.Browse.Browse.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(Browse.java:642)
    at com.aura.androidapp.Browse.Browse.onCreateView(Browse.java:605)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:824)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:500)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1621)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:742)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:607)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5378)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:340)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2368)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16834)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1312)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1509)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1189)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6223)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ripple_effect.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0200b1
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2152)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3579)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
    at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag ripple
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2148)
    ... 70 more
```

Here is the GenreAdater's getView method's snippet which the log cast is pointing :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if(convertView == null)
    {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.genre_list, parent, false);  //line number 709
    }
```

Here is the layout file genre_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:id="@+id/linear">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/pop"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" 
            android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="Rock"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="#f0f0f0"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the @drawable/ripple_effect.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#606060"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#606060" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Point to be noted is that it's working perfectly (even after uninstalling and redownloading from play store) on those device in which it was debuged while development. On new devices, after downloading from play store, it's crashing down.

Answer (score 1):

When you added tools:targetApi="lollipop" to your XML, this should've been a red flag to you ;-)  Android 4.4 is before Lollipop...

Ripple drawables were added in Android API 21, you are likely building your app with a new SDK version, but not handling compatibility properly so it will run on older versions of Android.

You may choose to set your minSdkVersion="21", and not support older versions of Android.

To support older versions, check out the compatibility library, or minimally create a separate *drawable-v21/ripple_effect.xml* with the ripple and *drawable/ripple_effect.xml* without the ripple, something like this:

**drawable-v21/ripple_effect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#606060"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#606060" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**drawable/ripple_effect.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#606060" />
        </shape>
</item>
```

Learn more here:  https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html